# Ionic 2 number input button without increment and decrement

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a number input button and I want it without increment and decrement which are on the right side of number input.

```
   <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-icon name="star" item-left ></ion-icon>
        <ion-label item-left >Standart 723128 </ion-label>
        <ion-icon item-right class="plus-minus" name="remove-circle" color="danger"(click)="decrement()"></ion-icon>
            <input type="number" item-right ng-model="currentNumber" style="text-align: center; width: 20%;" value="{{currentNumber}}">
        <ion-icon item-right class="plus-minus" name="add-circle" color="secondary" (click)="increment()"></ion-icon>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

Comment: And what is the problem you are facing? StackOverflow is not for request others to code for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you need this

[image]

use

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    margin: 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [NgModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) to bind currentNumber to the input and then increment or decrement its value

```
<ion-icon item-right class="plus-minus" name="remove-circle" color="danger" (click)="currentNumber--"></ion-icon>
<input type="number" item-right [(ngModel)]="currentNumber" />
<ion-icon item-right class="plus-minus" name="add-circle" color="secondary" (click)="currentNumber++"></ion-icon>
```